# Django instance.id always = 'None' when trying to set an upload location

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.6

Ive been trying to get my post form to allow users to upload a picture and then save it in a folder relative to the post id. However the post id is always == None.

Here in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your models here.

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "{}/{}".format(form.id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    post_content = models.TextField()
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:post_display", kwargs= {'post_id': self.id})
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

# Create your views here.
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

#create
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return(redirect("posts:post_timeline"))

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid() and request.POST:
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return(HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url()))


    context = {
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)


def post_edit(request, post_id = None):

    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id)

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = instance)
    if form.is_valid and request.POST and request.user.is_authenticated:
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        #messages.success(request, "Post successfully Edited")
        return(HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url()))
    context = {
        "title": instance.post_title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, "post_edit.html", context)
```

If you need any other code let me know,

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Why do you repeatedly save the form with commit=False and then immediately save the object?

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve] - The issue won't relate to all of your views for example

Comment: @DanielRoseman so that I can redirect the user to the post they just made

Comment: @Sayse Sorry, will do next time

Comment: That doesn't follow. `instance = form.save()` will give you a saved instance which you can use.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've changed that line of code. Thank you for pointing that out to me. However my issue with the location as to where the image is being saved still remains. Any further ideas/suggestions?